# pass result from AwaitReactions out of function discord.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, discord.js

I am new to async functions. I want to utilize the code below to ask the user a question and react to the question with an X or check mark to get the users answer on whether or not to delete something to make room for a new entry.

The function below works perfectly fine. However, I want to pass the result from the function out of the function so I can make an if else statement outside of it and that is where I am stuck.

I've looked around online and saw several things related to callbacks being used, but each example I've seen is different for something I think is similar, so I am just confused. And none of these examples have been used for Reactions on Discord, so I'm just not sure where to go.

```
     const agree = "✅"
     const disagree = "❌"
     let msg = await message.author.send("You have made the maximum number of decks. Would you like to delete one of your decks in order to make a new one? Please react with one of the following...")
     await msg.react(agree)
     await msg.react(disagree)


     const filter = (reaction, user) => {
     return ['✅', '❌'].includes(reaction.emoji.name) && user.id === message.author.id;
     };
     const reactions = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, {
        max: 1
        }).then(collected => {
        const result = collected.last();

        })
        return result;
        }

     deleteDeckQuestion(function(result){
        console.log(result)
        }).catch(err => console.error(err))
```

The above code results in 'undefined' being logged to the console when I run deleteDeckQuestion. No errors otherwise. I would like it to make the Results variable accessible to me outside the function so I can make an if else statement based upon which reaction the user added to the question.

I tried putting the if else statement I wanted to use with the results of deleteDeckQuestion inside the async function and it operated fine, but then inside the "Yes" result of that function, I want to put another Async function to ask which deck 1, 2 or 3 should be deleted and have the same reaction-determines-answer-to-question scenario. Just saves the user typing more than necessary at the ease of mobile users.

Would it be easier I just put an async function inside another async function? Something tells me that isn't the best idea in terms of efficiency. Eventually these reactions will lead to using mysql queries, which I am comfortable with using, but it will get pretty lengthy and functions inside other functions just seems like a mess... not sure if that is part of the "callback hell" I've read the joys of though...

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`collected` within your `then()` callback and `reactions` are the exact same object. However, `result`'s scope is limited to within the callback.

In this example code, `collected` is the result of `msg.awaitReactions(...)`'s fulfilled promise. Then, `result` is declared in the same scope, and therefore accessible where you need it to be.

```js
const collected = await msg.awaitReactions(filter, { max: 1 })
  .catch(console.error);

const result = collected.first();
```

MDN: [Async Programming](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await), [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await), [`then()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then), [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)
Discord.js: [`Message.awaitReactions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=awaitReactions)

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I substituted the example code for the latter portion of the function but the running of the function doesn't get anything logged to the console. No errors or anything, nothing gets logged at all.

Comment: `console.log(result)`?

Comment: Yeah. All I did was replace the "const reactions" to the end of the function block of my code with your example code. I left the very bottom block from my code alone and nothing happens when I run the command that this function is part of. It asks the question, reacts to the question with the correct reactions. I click the check mark reaction and nothing happens. Nothing logged at all.

Comment: I hope a screenshot is alright, since the code is all displayed above anyway. But this how I have it set up right now. https://i.gyazo.com/1a0e77cc44a8ae2d804f77340c85a198.png

Comment: In your function declaration, you're not declaring a parameter for a callback. You could use the same setup shown in this answer for the result of the function - `const result = await deleteDeckQuestion();`

Comment: Call me dumb (I probably am lol), but I'm unsure where to put that. I tried outside the function and, obviously, it says "await" needs to be inside an async function. When put inside the function if says "result has already been declared". I tried also putting "result" in the () in the first line of the function declaration and it also says result has already been declared. I replaced the declaration of "result" with that, as I expected, it just makes deleteDeckQuestion run a second time as soon as I click a reaction. I'm sorry I'm such a novice with this. :(

Comment: Make sure that where you're putting it is within an async function (`async function(...) {...}` or `async (...) => {...}`) to use `await`.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that. When I do place it inside the "async function deleteDeckQuestion" declaration line, it says that "result has already been declared". I must be missing something... Do you mean I place that line inside another function I want "result" to be fed into, perhaps? I don't plan to use it inside other functions directly, just into an if/else statement.

Comment: Replace the last lines of your snippet that call `deleteDeckQuestion()` with the `await` code. *That* line's context must be async.

Comment: but if I were to make the last lines of the last snippet to have await in it, that means I'd need to make it a whole other function, right? I don't need this variable to be in another function, I need it to be outside of a function so I can check its value for an if/else statement. Inside that if/else statement, there will be other functions that have nothing to do with "result".

Comment: Had to mess around a bit, but I got it working! Thanks so much for the help! :)

Last snippet ended up being as follows... ```(async function(){
  let result = await deleteDeckQuestion();
  console.log(result);
})();```

Didn't realize I needed to wipe the first line of shit snippet of the function name and only call it in the second line of the snippet. That is where I was confused!